# Dart URI: multiple query parameters with the same key

Tags: rest, dart, uri

I'm using [Mapquest directions API](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/directions-api/) and my goal is to create a route between a bunch of map points (3 and more).

Here is the API spec for "to" parameter [of the endpoint that's used to fetch a route for a given set of points](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/directions-api/route/get/) (it corresponds to the destination):

> When the input format is key/value pairs, the ending location(s) of a Route Request. More than one to parameter may be supplied. This is used for single-line addresses only.
>
> Refer to the Locations documentation on how to properly form locations in all formats, including JSON and XML.

AFAIK it means that multiple "to" parameters can be specified for a query, e.g. "http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/route?from=40.65,73.95&to=40.87,-73.85&to=40.70,-73.56 . Am I right about this?

So assuming that I understood the spec right, I need to construct an appropriate [`URI`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Uri-class.html) instance that will be dispatched to the http's library `get` method. The problem is that it receives a `Map<String, String` of query parameters in the constructor, and map means uniqueness. How can I construct such a request using `URI` class?

I've tried to make a workaround by just retrieving a string representation of an `URI` instance without specifying the `to` key-value pair and just writing the concatenated `to`-s in the end of the string with subsequent passing to the `http.get`. What I missed is that `URI` takes care for characters' escaping, and writing such a thing by myself seems to be completely inappropriate when the SDK already provides me with `URI` class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do not know if your reading is correct, but I can say how to create a URI with the same query parameter more than once.

The `Uri.parse` function does accept the same name more than once, but you are trying to create the string, so that's not useful

To create the URI from raw data, the constructor `Uri` has a `queryParameters` argument which accepts a `Map<String, dynamic>` where the value must be either a single `String` or an `Iterable<String>`. So, in your case:

```
var request = Uri.parse("http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/route")
    .resolveUri(Uri(queryParameters: {
      "from": "40.65,73.95",  
      "to": ["40.87,-73.85", "40.70,-73.56"],
    }));
```

If you have a query part which contains the same name more than once, then you need to use special functions on the `Uri` class to *read* those query parameters. The default `queryParameters` getter returns a `Map<String, String>` which can only have each name once. You can use the `queryParametersAll` getter instead.

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful